# ERROR: column "pitch_count" does not exist when it exists in an alias

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm running the following query in Rails 5, with the goal of finding the user with the most Pitches:

```rb
User
  .select("users.*, COUNT(user_id) as pitch_count")
  .unscoped
  .joins("LEFT JOIN pitches AS pitches ON pitches.user_id = users.id")
  .group("pitch.user_id")
  .order("pitch_count DESC")
  .limit(5)
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
Caused by PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "pitch_count" does not exist
```

Why isn't the query orderable by pitch_count?

Comment: Can you share the association between the models

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL do you use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem is in the [unscoped](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.3/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Default/ClassMethods.html#method-i-unscoped) method. It removes all previously defined scopes including `select` statement. See the following example:

```rb
User.select(:full_name, :email).unscoped.to_sql
# => SELECT "users".* FROM "users"

User.unscoped.select(:full_name, :email).to_sql
# => SELECT "users"."full_name", "users"."email" FROM "users"
```

See the difference? `unscoped` called after `select` definition completely removed every thing defined in the `select`.

For you this means that you should modify your code to call `unscoped` right after the model name:

```
User
  .unscoped
  .select("users.*, COUNT(user_id) as pitch_count")
  .joins("LEFT JOIN pitches AS pitches ON pitches.user_id = users.id")
  .group("pitch.user_id")
  .order("pitch_count DESC")
  .limit(5)
```

*Note: new lines added mostly for readability but it should work like this in your ruby files. If you want to execute it in the rails console. You will have to remove new lines*

---

Btw. you still might get error that column "user.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function. It should be fixed by modifying `group` statement to use `users.id` instead of `pitch.user_id`:

```
  .group("users.id")
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use [counter_cache](https://rubyinrails.com/2019/04/10/rails-counter-cache-associations/) to make it easy to maintain and good for performance as well. By adding counter cache, you can get the user record with most pitches by `User.reorder(pitches_count: :desc).first`.

Comment: Meaning that you don't want to use counter_cache or the query doesn't work after adding counter_cache?

Comment: Counter cache is not trust-worthy, and should be used only when data accuracy is not a concern.